# How to generate an heterogeneous mesh

Tags: graphics, random, mesh, lattices, computational-geometry

I'd like to generate a mesh with a big variance in cell size. Something like

[image]

I'd prefer not to rely on a vertex model and perhaps use something simpler, like `VoronoiMesh`. Any ideas?

**Further comments:** I'd simply like to get a mesh-type object with varying cell sizes and similar to the picture above. Not much else is required. When using `VoronoiMesh` I might need to tweak the distribution of the random points in order to better mimic the image. Simply using `VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[1, {300, 2}]]`, for example, is not "diverse enough". I've also heard of weighted Voronoi tessellations, but I want to keep the polygon-shaped mesh. A clustering distribution of points, with multiple clusters, should do the trick, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is the issue with `VoronoiMesh`? Do you want the colors? What is it in particular you are trying to do?

Comment: @bRost03 I've edited the question to add some details. No color needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get clustered points from a random point process and then relax the Voronoi mesh. The final mesh is the variable `relaxed`:

```
SeedRandom[123];
proc = CauchyPointProcess[15, 35, 0.005, 2];
data = RandomPointConfiguration[proc, Rectangle[]];
bounds = {{0, 1}, {0, 1}};
mesh = VoronoiMesh[data["Points"], {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];
relaxed = Nest[VoronoiMesh[Mean @@@ MeshPrimitives[#, 2], bounds] &, mesh, 5];
Graphics[Table[{RandomColor[], p}, {p, MeshPrimitives[relaxed, 2]}]]
```

[image: voronoi with clusters]